# AngularJS Directive - How can I tell if attribute's expression is fully evaluated?

Tags: angularjs

Say I have a directive that accepts an attribute named "url" that could be made up of expressions and static texts, and the evaluated result of "url" will be used as the url of a ng-include in the directive's template. How do I check, **from inside the directive**, that the attribute is fully evaluated (i.e. all expressions defined) before I try to use it so that I don't get a 404 error every time?

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.form = { id: 'test' };
  }, 1000)
})
.directive('ngMyForm', function() {
  return {
    template: '<div ng-include="formUrl"></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      attrs.$observe('url', function(value) {
        // how do I make sure that value's expression is fully "resolved" before using it?
        scope.formUrl = value;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-my-form="{{form.id}}_sometext" url="/form/{{form.id}}_sometext"></div>
</body>
```

I've set up a plunk here: http://plnkr.co/edit/MDhUpT?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute is always "fully evaluated". It's just that the expressions it contains are evaluated to an empty string, and are later evaluated to something else. The directive can't guess when an expression is supposed to be correct and when it's supposed to be incorrect. The *user* of the directive should just not use it while the URL is unknown. For example:

```
 <div ng-if="form.id" ng-my-form url="/form/{{form.id}}_sometext"></div>
```